# Python: invert image with transparent background (PIL, Gimp,...)

Tags: python, transparency, python-imaging-library, gimp

I have a set of white icons on transparent background, and I'd like to invert them all to be black on transparent background.

[image]

Have tried with PIL (ImageChops) but it does not seem to work with transparent backgrounds. I've also tried Gimp's Python interface, but no luck there, either.

Any idea how inverting is best achieved in Python?

Comment: their file format is png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ImageChops.invert` seems to also invert the alpha channel of each pixel.

This should do the job:

```
import Image

img = Image.open('image.png').convert('RGBA')

r, g, b, a = img.split()

def invert(image):
    return image.point(lambda p: 255 - p)

r, g, b = map(invert, (r, g, b))

img2 = Image.merge(img.mode, (r, g, b, a))

img2.save('image2.png')
```

Comment: Instead of defining your own `invert()` you could just use `ImageOps.invert()` on each channel since each channel has type `"L"`. (or I suppose `ImageChops.invert()` but I've never tested that myself).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Acorn's approach, but the result is somewhat strange (top part of the below image).

[image]

The bottom icon is what I really wanted, I achieved it by using [Image Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s convert method:

`convert tools.png -negate tools_black.png`

(not python per se, but python wrappers exist, like [PythonMagickWand](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonMagickWand/0.2).

The only drawback is that you have to install a bunch of dependencies to get ImageMagick to work, but it seems to be a powerful image manipulation framework.

Comment: Right, the code I posted was only converting white pixels to black. I've updated my answer with a generic inversion.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Image, numpy
pixels = numpy.array(Image.open('myimage.png'))
pixels[:,:,0:3] = 255 - pixels[:,:,0:3] # invert
Image.fromarray(pixels).save('out.png')
```

Probably the fastest solution so far, since it doesn't interpret any Python code inside a "for each pixel" loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this quite easily with `PIL`, like this:

1. Ensure the image is represented as `RGBA`, by using `convert('RGBA')`.
2. Split the image into seperate `RGBA` bands.
3. Do what ever you want to the `RGB` bands (in your case we set them all to black by using the `point` function), but don't touch the alpha band.
4. Merge the bands back.

heres the code:

```
import Image
im = Image.open('image.png')
im = im.convert('RGBA')
r, g, b, a = im.split()
r = g = b = r.point(lambda i: 0)
im = Image.merge('RGBA', (r, g, b, a))
im.save('saved.png')
```

give it a shot.